# passing pointers of character arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a function which starts like this :

```
 void fun(char *in,char *po)
 {
     char *i,*p;
     i=&in[0];
     p=&po[0];
     //some operation with *i and *p
}
```

Why is that code correct and why does it give a warning for the one below :

```
   void fun(char *in,char *po)
    {
      char *i,*p;
      i=&in;
      p=&po;
      //some operation with *i and *p
 }
```

In main i call the function like this :

```
fun(&arr1[0],&arr2[0]);
```

Since we are passing the address to the first index of both the arrays why does the second code not work ?Nor did I understand the pointer &in[0] having to specify an index no. cause it is just a pointer and not an array . Pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `&in[0]` gives you a pointer to the first element in the array pointed to by `in`. Its type is `char *`.

The expression `&in` gives you a pointer to the pointer `in`, and the type is `char **`. Quite different from the first.

---

Also note that you don't need `&in[0]`, just doing `i = in` would work just as well.

Reason being that `in[0]` is equivalent to `*(in + 0)`, which means that `&in[0]` is equivalent to `&*(in + 0)` and the address-of and dereference operators cancel each other out, so it's equivalent to `(in + 0)` which of course is the same as just plain `in`.

Furthermore note that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, so `fun(&arr1[0],&arr2[0])` is the same as `fun(arr1, arr2)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `i = &in;`, type of `i` is `char *` while type of `&in` is `char **` causing the type mismatch in assignation and thus the warning. You should avoid assignation from different types.

If you know what you are doing, an explicit typecast is required unless atleast one of the type is `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case (`i=&in[0];`) you assign the address of the first element of the array to `i` (this address is of type `char*`.

In the second case (`i=&in;`) you assign the address of the parameter `in` to `i` and since `in` is of type `char*`, the address is of type `char**` and that causes your warning.